# When I call Bitmap.Save function occur error "A generic error occurred in GDI+"

Tags: c#

When I call `Bitmap.Save` function, this error occurs: "A generic error occurred in GDI+". When I call from localhost it work, but when I call from another computer this error occurs.

**Server Error in '/jobnumber' Application:**

> A generic error occurred in GDI+. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

> [ExternalException (0x80004005): A
>   generic error occurred in GDI+.]
>   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String
>   filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder,
>   EncoderParameters encoderParams)
>   +377518    System.Drawing.Image.Save(String
>   filename, ImageFormat format) +69
>   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String
>   filename) +25
>   Assignment.CreateBitmapImage(String
>   sImageText, Image Image1, JobInfo
>   job_info_param) +124
>   Assignment.PrintButton_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +271
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e) +111
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +110
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   +13    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection
>   postData) +36
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

Comment: What do you mean with "call from another computer"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is usually an indication the web user (IIS_USR for example) has no rights to
save any data to the folder where you are saving the bitmap on the webserver.

I had similar problems before. Check the access rights on the server for that folder.
Start out by giving everyone full access to that folder (just to make sure that is the problem) then narrow it down again so only the required user has access.