# Saving image file to windows azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, azure, bitmap

So, I'd like to save the user's profile picture on the disk. To do this, I call the `SaveUserProfilePicture` method, which is working fine on my local system but not on Azure.

```
public static string SaveUserProfilePicture(Stream image, string subDirectory)
{
    return SaveImageFile(new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(image)), subDirectory);
}

private static string SaveImageFile(Bitmap bitmap, string subDirectory)
{
    var virtualPath = string.Format("~/Images/{0}/{1}.jpg", subDirectory, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    bitmap.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(virtualPath));

    return virtualPath;
}
```

The exception:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

[ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.]
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) +473402
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format) +69
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename) +25
   MyProject.Core.Helpers.ImageLoader.SaveImageFile(Bitmap bitmap, String subDirectory) +136
   MyProject.Core.Helpers.ImageLoader.SaveUserProfilePicture(Stream image, String subDirectory) +87
   MyProject.Controllers.AccountController.ChangeProfilePicture(HttpPostedFileBase choosenPhoto) +52
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14

I'd mention that I have a free trial subscription(so not shared or anything). Moreover, is there any way to see the files on my Azure folder(i.e. under the Images directory)?

Comment: You are saving it to local disk? I'd advise against that. You should think about saving it to blob storage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I call Bitmap.Save function occur error "A generic error occurred in GDI+"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796999/when-i-call-bitmap-save-function-occur-error-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi)

Comment: @Arran So, here are the pricing details of the windows azure web-sites: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/ Is the "Storage" row refers to the blob storage? Or why would I pay for another storage environment? Why can't I simply use the local disk?

Comment: @laszlokiss88, as you appear to be using Azure web sites, you can forget my comment. Saving to local disk is fine for Web Sites, but for Azure cloud services (i.e having web roles, worker roles etc), saving to local disk isn't a good idea because it's transient data. You cannot guarantee it's persistence. Your instance may be taken down at any time without warning and replaced with a new instance of your deployment. Therefore it's a brand new drive with your website on it, and you've lost all the images. However, you can forget this :)